# CSS scrollbar not working outside of Chrome?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'm using this CSS code in order to customize my scroll bar style:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 8px;
} /* this targets the default scrollbar (compulsory) */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: black;
} /* the new scrollbar will have a flat appearance with the set background color */
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: #59e5f6;
      border-radius: 10px;
} /* this will style the thumb, ignoring the track */
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
      background-color: black;
} /* optionally, you can style the top and the bottom buttons (left and right for horizontal bars) */
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
      background-color: black;
} /* if both the vertical and the horizontal bars appear, then perhaps the right bottom corner also needs to be styled */

body {
    scrollbar-face-color: black;
}
```

It works great on Chrome, but not other browsers.

Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Well, the fact that these properties all start with -webkit- is a big clue: those other browsers simply don't have this. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar), for instance. So, no.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.
Do you know what should I use?

Comment: There are probably JavaScript libraries that allow you to do that. Not familiar with any of those though.

Comment: Please, never do this, unless you wish to annoy the heck out of pretty much everyone. Leave my scrollbars alone.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported in IE, Edge and Firefox by default.
Here is screenshot from documentation 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

[image]

Note: You can use javascript libraries like 
[perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar)